# How to change the color of animated in android programmiticaly?

Tags: android, animation, background, shapes

I have shape in res/drawable/back.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="85dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="5dp"
    android:useLevel="false">
    <solid
        android:color="#FF0000">
    </solid>
    <size
        android:height="200dp"
        android:width="200dp">
    </size>
</shape>
```

This shape set in background on TextView:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:keepScreenOn="true"
        android:textColor="#33b5e5"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/dummy_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:background="@drawable/back" />
```

I need infinitely change color (random color - is done) of animation on shape.
In the end, I need to ring around the text, which will be constantly animated color change.

*P.S. Sorry for my english. I partly use a translator.* **Thanks!**

Java code:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.RectF;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
        findViewById(R.id.button3).setOnClickListener(btn3Click);
    }


   public View.OnClickListener btn3Click = new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
           GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) textView.getBackground();
           drawable.setColor(randColor());
       }
   };
    public int randColor(){
        Random rnd = new Random();
        return Color.argb(255, rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256), rnd.nextInt(256));
    }
}
```

**This effect:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
var colours=['#ff3333','#33cc66','#3399cc'];  // List of colors
    var tempID=0;
    var changeInterval=2000;    // Change interval in miliseconds
    var objectID='#bgDiv';      // Object to change colours. 
    
    $(document).ready(function(){        
        setInterval(function(){
                $(objectID).animate({backgroundColor: colours[tempID]},500);
                tempID=tempID+1;
                if (tempID>colours.length-1) tempID=0;
            },changeInterval);
    });
</script>
<style> 
#bgDiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #3399cc;
    border-radius:100px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="bgDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i m not sure but you can try this GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable) myImg.getDrawable();
drawable.setColor(color)

Comment: where is the animation color change? or how to implement it?

Comment: insert the above code whevenevr you wanna change the color, could you see color variable in second statement?that chnages the color

Comment: I do not understand you... ((

Comment: atleast try to add the above code

Comment: Ok. It works. But there is no **animation**  when changing colors.

Comment: ok let me try, post you complete code how you used back.xml and applyied the animation

Comment: Send a code which is used back.xml and how I use GradiendDrawable?

Comment: just post the java code here

Comment: I did what you asked.

Comment: ok let me try on my end

Comment: could you plz tell me how id animation looks like before adding my code?

Comment: i do not use animation object.

Comment: thats what i m asking what extactly output you are looking for? i mean in any example you can gve or image you can show?

Comment: I can analog on [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation1) . Please click 'See Result'. I need this animation for my shape,slow color change.

Comment: @diva I found best example - [Animation](http://tjvantoll.com/demos/2012-02-20/basic.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would achieve this as below :

```
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    int i = 0;
    ImageView frameanimation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        frameanimation = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
        AnimationDrawable frame_animation = (AnimationDrawable) frameanimation
                .getBackground();
        frame_animation.setVisible(true, true);
        frame_animation.start();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new RunTimer(), 0, 1500);
    }

    class RunTimer extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(runnn);
        }

        Runnable runnn = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0.7F);
                alpha.setDuration(1000);
                frameanimation.startAnimation(alpha);
            }
        };
    }

}
```

Added complete source code [here](https://github.com/mtetno/Animation)

OutPut:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I implemented a little differently. Everything just use a timer, but the change of color is different. Here java code:            currentColor=randColor();
                Drawable drawable = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content).getBackground();
                ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(drawable, "color",previousColor, currentColor).setDuration(2000);
                objectAnimator.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
                objectAnimator.start();
                previousColor=currentColor;

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#rrggbb"));
```

or

```
root.setBackgroundColor(0xrrggbb);
```

Chose a random number hexadecimal 6 digit number, and pass it as the argument of any of the above functions. It should work.

Comment: Works with animation?

Comment: okay! So you can select a random value, and move from your present state to next state. eg: your current position is 001122, and your next random value is 00112A, so you can use a simple loop which takes you from 001122 to 00112A, in a given amount of time.

Comment: depends on you. usually its better to do such stuff from another thread. But then there will be a problem. In case you leave the activity, it will reopen the activity till the Thread is alive. So, you should take care of this thing.